# Can't present popover controller

Tags: ios, swift

```
func displayPopover() {

    let popController = UIViewController()
    popController.view.backgroundColor = .red

    // set up the popover presentation controller
    popController.modalPresentationStyle = .popover
    popController.popoverPresentationController?.permittedArrowDirections = UIPopoverArrowDirection.up
    popController.popoverPresentationController?.delegate = self
    popController.popoverPresentationController?.sourceView = self.view
    popController.popoverPresentationController?.sourceRect = CGRect(x: 100, y: 100, width: 100, height: 100)

    // present the popover
    self.present(popController, animated: true, completion: nil)
}

func adaptivePresentationStyleForPresentationController(controller: UIPresentationController!) -> UIModalPresentationStyle {
    // Return no adaptive presentation style, use default presentation behaviour
    return .none
}
```

It displays the popover like any other view controller, sliding from the bottom displaying a red screen.

Comment: Are you checking it on iPhone or iPad? I think you are checking on iPhone

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As per documentation

> In a horizontally regular environment, a presentation style where the content is displayed in a popover view. The background content is dimmed and taps outside the popover cause the popover to be dismissed. If you do not want taps to dismiss the popover, you can assign one or more views to the passthroughViews property of the associated UIPopoverPresentationController object, which you can get from the popoverPresentationController property.
>   In a horizontally compact environment, this option behaves the same as fullScreen.

For iPhones `popOver` will behave same like fullscreen and for iPad it will be displayed in a popover view.

Answer (score 1):

To get the "popup" effect:

1.You should make viewController in storyboard and then add view inside it like this(also add constraints):

[image]

2.You should declare the popover like this:

```
let popOverVC = UIStoryboard(name: "Main", bundle: nil).instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier("popupID") as! PopUpViewController
self.addChildViewController(popOverVC)
popOverVC.view.frame = self.view.frame
self.view.addSubview(popOverVC.view)
popOverVC.didMoveToParentViewController(self)
```

3.Now you should make the background darker and transparent like this `self.view.backgroundColor = UIColor.blackColor().colorWithAlphaComponent(0.8)` in `viewDidLoad()`

4.And to open it(it also animates it slightly):

```
self.view.transform = CGAffineTransformMakeScale(1.3, 1.3)
        self.view.alpha = 0.0;
        UIView.animateWithDuration(0.25, animations: {
            self.view.alpha = 1.0
            self.view.transform = CGAffineTransformMakeScale(1.0, 1.0)
        });
```